# Terminal Password

Tags: linux, bash

So, I'm trying to make a password script, and it works for the most part. However, the loop goes on forever, instead of stopping after each "Incorrect Password", so the user can type in a password. However it keeps spamming Incorrect Password and gives no chance of typing anything at all.
I also tried putting `read password` under the until line, but this didn't work either.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Dom (GlitchyShadowZ)
# No name lol
# Password Protected Terminal

echo "Please enter password to continue"
str="owo"
read password

until [ $password = $str ]
do
    # Password Verification
    if [ $password = $str ];
    then
        echo "Password correct. Logging in"
    else
        echo "Password Incorrect. Try again."
    fi
done
```

Comment: You need to `read password` inside the loop or else it will never change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read a password every time before comparing it. Also, you are checking the `$password = $str` condition twice - it's not necessary. You can check only once by completely removing `if` from the loop and moving the `Password correct. Logging in` at the end of the script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Dom (GlitchyShadowZ)

# No name lol

# Password Protected Terminal

echo "Please enter password to continue"
str="owo"
read password

until [ "$password" = "$str" ]
do
    echo "Password Incorrect. Try again."
    read password
done

echo "Password correct. Logging in"
```

or use `while true` together with `break` inside loop when the correct password is entered:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Author: Dom (GlitchyShadowZ)

# No name lol

# Password Protected Terminal


str="owo"
password=""

echo "Please enter password to continue"

while true
do
    read password
    # Password Verification
    if [ "$password" = "$str" ];
    then
    echo "Password correct. Logging in"
    break
    else
    echo "Password Incorrect. Try again."
    fi
done
```

In both cases make sure to put `""` around your variables because currently when your script is run and nothing is typed and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed immediately you get this:

```
line 13: [: =: unary operator expected
```